# Accessing foreign key attributes for arithmetics in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I'm trying to calculate the length of a house relative to some adjacent neighborhoods, such that, house_size / (neighborhood[0].length + neighborhood[1].length...):

```py
class House(models.Model):
    house_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)                             
    size = models.IntegerField()
    neighborhood = models.ManyToManyField('neighborhood', through='HouseNeighborhoodLink')
```

```py
class Neighborhood(models.Model):
    length = models.IntegerField()
```

I created a table to assign several neighborhoods with a house. Also, houses can be assigned to several adjacent neighborhoods:

```py
class HouseNeighborhoodLink(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    neighborhood = models.ForeignKey(Neighborhood, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Serializers:

```py
class LengthFromNeighborhoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Neighborhood
        fields = ['length']        


class HouseCoverageOfNeighborhood(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Neighborhood = LengthFromNeighborhoodSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = HouseNeighborhoodLink
        fields = ['house_id', 'Neighborhood']
```

I'm stuck in the three dots (...), where I want to access the length attribute of all neighborhoods and then calculate the proportion to a house. I'm not sure how to access the length of each neighborhood from HouseNeighborhoodLink table:

```py
class HouseCoverageDetail(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = HouseNeighborhoodLink.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HouseCoverageOfNeighborhood

    def get_queryset(self):
        house_id = self.kwargs['house_id']
        neighborhood = self.queryset.filter(house_id=house_id)
        ...
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Chack this

```
 class HouseCoverageOfNeighborhood(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Neighborhood = LengthFromNeighborhoodSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = HouseNeighborhoodLink
        fields = ['house_id', 'Neighborhood']
```

Comment: When I add `many=True` I get "Neighborhood object is not iterable"